# How to prove that a function is well-defined?

Tags: functions

I have this function: $$f(x)=\frac{1}{3}(x-3), f:(0,6] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
I tried to prove that the function is well defined like so:
$$x \in (0,6] \Rightarrow 0<x\le6$$
$$-3<x-3\le3$$
$$-1<\frac{1}{3}(x-3)\le1$$
The first time I subtracted 3, and in the second time I multiplied by $\frac{1}{3}$.

Is this method valid?

Comment: Seem ok to me. Just add 'In particular, $f(x)\in \Bbb R$

Comment: Of course! Thank you. Just started to learn this subject and needed to check it.

Answer (score 1):

You even overcomplicated it: If $x\in (0,6]$, the $x\in \Bbb R$. As $\Bbb R$ is a field, we can add, subtract, multiply, and divide (the latter only by non-zero). Hence $\frac13(x-3)\in\Bbb R$ as desired, i.e., this expression can be used to *define* the function $f$.

Comment: I know but next I'll have to find the image of the function, so it should be helpful, right? because I know now it's (-1, 1]. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @BeardGuy367 You should state the problem correctly! The inequality you prove has more or less nothing to do with showing $f$ is well-defined, which is all you asked - if you also need to find the image of $f$ you should say so in the question! (Note the "Edit" link...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Noted, thank you. I'll be clearer next time.

Comment: @BeardGuy367 would be better to just fix this one. Click where it says "Edit", just below the question...